# Verify all columns of the array for a determined pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have the following javascript code

```
var list = [
{
  Date : '2014-12-31 12:23:43',
  DateStart: '1980-12-30 23:43:42',
  Name: 'Kate',
  ...
  ...
},
{
  Date : '1978-05-21 23:43:65',
  DateStart: '1973-04-06 12:34:09',
  Name: 'John',
  ...
  ...
}
];
```

And the following code to verify for regex pattern:

```
for (var i in list) {
     var data = [];
     if (/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/.test(list[i].?)) {
         data.push({Data: list[i].Data });
     }
}
```

The variable `i` from the above code is to interact with each line of the array.

How can I interact through for loops with each line and column without having to specify this in the question mark from the above code?

What can I do to all columns be verified for the date pattern?

Making the array `date` stay only with the values

```
2014-12-31 12:23:43,
1980-12-30 23:43:42,
1978-05-21 23:43:65,
1973-04-06 12:34:09
```

Comment: It's an array of objects. `column = list[5].Date`

Comment: But I want that the `column` stay with the Data value instead 00/00/0000

Comment: "stay"? huh? You want `column` to be more of a pointer to a specific entry in `list`? Not really possible. JS doesn't have pointers.

Comment: Need a far better explanation of objectives. Please put more effort into your questions so that they are clear and concise. Also provide expected results

Comment: We need more detailed information on what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to extract everything that is a date from your object? What part of your code doesn't work? Can you come up with a jsfiddle to help us view your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was this what I wanted

```
for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        for (p in list[j]) {
            if (/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/.test(list[j][p])) {
                data.push({Data: list[j][p] });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I interact through for loops with each line and column without having to specify this in the question mark from the above code?

You **have to** specify the field you want to access, how else should the interpreter be able to know what you want to access?

If you want to avoid using an indexer you can use external libraries like `underscore.js` to iterate over the collection:

http://underscorejs.org/#each

```
_.each(list, function(item) { 
  // validate item.Date and item.DateStart here
});
```

Alternatively there is a very concise post about this topic here: [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I put `_.each(list, function(item) { 
            var data = [];
            if (/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/.test(item.Data)) {
                data.push({ Data: item.Data });
            }
        });`, but it only verifies the specified column. I want to verify column by column, line by line, to verify if the pattern matches. Like when you are going to verify a table `for(line=0;line<line.qtd;line++){for(column=0;column<column.qtd;column++){}}`@ovm